# How do I load my site without the side bars? This is for an app

Tags: sidebar

My site has a left side bar where I display categories and ads and what not. We are creating a basic android app for it and we are trying to figure out how to load the site on the app without sidebars. I know that I can disable the side bars in the options of WP but I don't want to disable them because I want people to be able to see the sidebar when they visit the site. Is there a trick to just loading the site without including the side bar? I just want to target the middle frame of the site. Any help would be appreciated.

site: tablified.com

Comment: Remove the_sidebar() in your template file conditionally, probably based on the User-Agent header fingerprint retrieved by $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].

Comment: Note the question tag. If this is a **wordpress.com** site, the OP won't have the option to modify template files.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the theme files? If so, try replacing `<?php get_sidebar() ?>;` with this:

```
<?php
if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'android') === FALSE ) {
    get_sidebar();
}
?>
```

Otherwise, what about access to the theme's javascript file?

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    // Perhaps target the CSS to hide the sidebar (display:none;)?
}
```

EDIT:

You can also try loading a stylesheet after the default one that targets mobile devices. Use the media attribute when loading the stylesheet:

```
<link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

Alternatively you can just add some declarations into your existing stylesheet:

```
// target small screens (mobile devices or small desktop windows)  
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {  
    /* CSS goes here */  
}
```

Comment: Note the question tag. If this is a **wordpress.com** site, the OP won't have the option to modify template files.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, I do have a dedicated hosted WP. I can access the theme files. tried searching for this <?php get_sidebar() ?>; and I could not find it anywhere. Its most likely due to the fact that I have a custom theme. Is there some place that I can place it to overwrite all other commands? like in the style.css?

Comment: From a quick look at your site, this is not a matter of simply hiding the sidebar. You will have to make some significant changes to the CSS. I suggest you do one of two things: 
1. make use of `@media` in your stylesheet to target mobile devices, OR, 2. Search for `id="sidebar"` in your theme files and include the `if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'android') === FALSE ){}` to determine whether the sidebar is shown or not. I would also use this method to conditionally load a secondary stylesheet `android.css` that adjusts the theme accordingly.

Comment: [Look here](http://pugetworks.com/2011/04/css-media-queries-for-targeting-different-mobile-devices/) for more information on targeting specific mobile devices using CSS media queries.